# Determine two properties of a trig function

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, optimization, exponential-function, periodic-functions

I've the following questions:

> Find the period of the function $\text{f}\left(t\right)$ and determine the time where the function reach a local maximum for the first time for $t\ge0$.

The function is given as follows:

$$f\left(t\right)=a\cdot\left(b\cdot z+c\cdot x\right)\tag1$$

Where $a,b,c$ are real constants and:

$$z=\exp\left(rt\right)\cdot\left(y\cos\left(yt\right)+r\sin\left(yt\right)\right)\space\wedge\space x=\exp\left(rt\right)\cdot\sin\left(yt\right)\tag2$$

Where $r,y$ are real constants and $t\ge0$ is the time.

---

My work:

The period of the function is (I think) given by:

$$T=\frac{2\pi}{y}\tag3$$

And for the second question I tried:

$$f'(t)=0\tag4$$

But I do not how that leads to a solution

Comment: Maybe I'm asking a dumb question, but are you struggling with why solving for when the derivative is zero you may have a maximum? Or are you struggling with the derivative itself? Or is it more of a I solved that part, but now what?

Comment: @KitterCatter No I can find the derivative but I do not see how I can solve the first timepoint where the local maximum occurs.